# In the US, isn't property tax for our house unconstitutional?

Tags: us-constitution, constitutional-rights

We are usually taxed at 1.2%, and that means in 80 years, it is 96% of the house and it is devoured alive.

The Constitution said people have the Rights to Properties.  It does not says, "People have the Rights to Properties ONLY WHEN THEY PAY UP."

For example, if Peter has the rights to property, and he doesn't have money, and now his house is taken away, or that his food money is taken away, now he doesn't have the rights to the property. (or he will have the "rights" to the property and without food he'd be dead.)  The Constitution never said you don't have the rights to the property when you CANNOT PAY UP.

Comment: Won't the value of the house go up in 80 years?

Comment: "The Constitution said people have the Rights to Properties".  Does it, though? Not anywhere in the text that I can see.  Would you please show which passage in the Constitution you are referring to here?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey it is taxed at the current value of the house, so it is 1.2% every year of that current value, so 80 years and it is 96%. Note that inflation doesn't make the house have higher "value".  My lunch was $3.50 and now it is $11, and my house was $680k and now $1.7 million but it really didn't go up in "value". It just went up with inflation. I also need to pay the fake "capital gain tax" when I sell the house when the house didn't go up in value because everything went up in prices.

Comment: You can say tomorrow, the $1 bill is called $3 and the Earth goes around the same way but you can tax me on the "capital gain" for $2

Comment: it is that it seems whoever can tax you or make you pay, they will. City sales tax, County property tax, State income tax, Federal income tax, and I chose a house with a Home Owner Association. They "special assessment"'ed us for $90,000, changing roofs that was merely 7 years old just because "they want nice matching black color", and replaced and threw away all the good windows, sliding door just to get "a warranty for the siding". There are 5 layers of power that are taxing people here, when they can

Answer (score 3):

> The Constitution said people have the Rights to Properties.

No it doesn't. There is no such provision. The closest I am aware of is the so-called "takings clause" in the Fifth Amendment, which reads:

> Nor shall private property be taken for public use without just compensation.

There has been a good deal of litigation over just when when a "taking" occurs under this provision. The classic and most obvious case is the use of eminent domain to aquire actual title to the property by a government (Federal, State, or local). This is always a takign, and compensation nis required. The more questionable cases have occurred when some law or regulation leaves the owner with title, but significantly restricts the uses to which the property may be put, particularly when the existing use becomes unlawful. Courts have ruled in different ways in such cases, but I think the current standard is that when a regulation removes all, or almost all, economic value from the property there has been a "regulatory taking" and compensation must be paid.

But as far as I know, a tax on the property has never been considered to be a taking inn this sense.

Comment: It might be useful to post a Q&A about what s direct tax is in US law.

Answer (score 2):

### Maybe, that’s why there isn’t one

There are plenty of *state* property taxes administered by local government but the USA doesn’t have one.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://www.americanbar.org/groups/taxation/publications/abataxtimes_home/19aug/19aug-pp-johnson-a-wealth-tax-is-constitutional/) gives a good overview of constitutional tax power, even though it has a pro-tax bias. A distinction is made between direct and indirect taxes. The Constitution allows "direct taxes", provided that they are given to the states in proportion to population, ergo Wyoming and Alaska would receive very little of the money, and California and Texas would get most of the money. This would be a politically unpopular outcome plus since you give the money to the states, so why not leave it to the states to do that which is unpopular (which is what they do now).

A special constitutional amendment, [the 16th](https://constitution.congress.gov/constitution/amendment-16/), was passed which enabled a non-apportioned direct federal tax but only on income. Then the question arises, what happens if you don't pay your federal income taxes? As you know, one of the sticks that the government can wield is the power to seize property from people, in payment of lawful debts to the government (known as a "levy"). They can do this under [26 USC 6331](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/6331) – Congress passed a law that is "necessary and proper" to enforce another law (imposing an income tax, which is constitutionally allowed). Seizure of property *is* allowed under the constitution under the Dur Process clauses (5th, 14th Amendments), which allows deprivation of property only according to the operation of law (as opposed to personal whim of the marshal). There is a law. There does *not* happen to be a federal property tax, so the IRS cannot seize your property for non-payment of non-existent federal property takes.

Comment: "The Constitution allows "direct taxes", provided that they are given to the states in proportion to population," This is incorrect. The apportionment clause requires that any direct tax be **collected** in proportion to population.  This is so unwieldy that AFAIK no direct tax has ever been levied by the US federal govt, and when a tax is held by a court to be direct, that amounts to holding the tax unconstitutional [...]

Comment: That is why a constitutional amendment was deemed needed to authorize the Federal income tax, which was argued to be a direct tax.

Comment: I think that the ABA article linked in the answer actually does a very poor job of expounding what was and is considered a direct tax under the Federal Constitution. It ignores that the same formula was used for apportionment of direct taxes and representatives, and this was considered a significant safeguard. If its contentions were correct, there would have been no need for the Sixteenth Amendment.  It ignores the case which held the income tax unconstitutional, where the distinction was reviewed in detail.

Comment: It might be useful to post a Q&A about what s direct tax is in US law.